# how to extract "url "using regualr expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

[image: i had the kept same thing but still error occurs][image: extracted url from 1st request[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B6BL.png)

"url": "https://tinypng.com/web/output/96xgbqc264xu4xfkckc40x7xmkybu6ra"

Need to extract the url and https from the above url can any one suggest me how to extract it from regular expression extractor using jmeter

how to pass the extracted url to pass into another request

Answer (score 0):

Your response is utterly like to be a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) therefore it makes more sense to consider using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/), the relevant JSON Path query will be as simple as `$.url`.

If you still want the regular expression it would be something like:

```
"url"\s?:\s?"(.+?)"
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter - Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: thanks dmitiri and how to pass the extracted url to subsequent request to download the file

Comment: Put the `${url}` environment variable reference into "Path" section of the HTTP Request sampler. You might also want to use [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener to store the file to your hard drive. Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/) article for more details.

Comment: i had kept the same thing but still error occurs i.ejava.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 21: https://tinypng.com/${output}